# Creating a SCD from several source tables and overlapping date periods

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Given the following source tables.

```
 CREATE TABLE prices
(
   Style     CHAR(10),
   Size      CHAR(10),
   BeginDate DATE,
   EndDate   DATE,
   price     DECIMAL(18, 2)
)

INSERT INTO prices
            (Style,
             Size,
             BeginDate,
             EndDate,
             price)
VALUES      ('B100',NULL,'1-10-2010','1-30-2010',-5),
            ('B101',NULL,'1-10-2010','1-15-2010',-10),
            ('B102',NULL,'1-10-2010','1-15-2010',-20),
            ('B100','32x32','1-10-2010','1-15-2010',-1),
            ('B100','32x34','1-11-2010','1-20-2010',-2),
            ('B100','32x36','1-01-2010','1-15-2010',-3),
            ('B100','32x38','1-10-2010','2-15-2010',-4)

CREATE TABLE Products
(
   ProductKey INT,
   Style      CHAR(10),
   Size       CHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO Products
            (ProductKey,
             Style,
             Size)
VALUES      (1,'B100','32x32'),
            (2,'B100','32x34'),
            (3,'B100','32x36'),
            (4,'B100','32x38'),
            (5,'B100','32x40'),
            (6,'B101','32x32'),
            (7,'B101','32x34'),
            (8,'B101','32x36'),
            (9,'B101','32x38'),
            (10,'B101','32x40'),
            (11,'B102','32x32'),
            (12,'B103','32x34'),
            (13,'B103','32x36'),
            (14,'B103','32x38'),
            (15,'B103','32x40')
```

I need to produce the following output

```
ProductKey  BeginDate   EndDate     Price
1           1-10-2010   1-15-2010   -1
1           1-16-2010   1-30-2010   -5
2           1-10-2010   1-10-2010   -5
2           1-11-2010   1-20-2010   -2
2           1-21-2010   1-30-2010   -5
etc....
```

So the prices table is a SCD of discounts.  The discounts can be applied at the style level, or at the individual size level.

A size level discount overrides the style level discount for a particular time period.  Time periods can overlap in pretty much anyway.

[The question is similar to the one I asked a year ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214927/dates-and-timespans-with-sql)  I'm having huge issues trying to wrap my mind around how to do this without resorting to cursors or while loops.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b95c3/9)

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT p.*,s1.BeginDate, s1.EndDate, s1.price
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN prices s1
 ON p.Style = s1.Style
 AND p.Size = s1. Size
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT
  c.PRODUCTKEY, c.STYLE, c.SIZE
  , DATEADD(day,1,c.EndDate)
  , s.EndDate
  , s.Price
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN prices s
 ON c.Style = s.Style
 AND s.Size IS NULL
 AND c.EndDate > s.BeginDate AND c.EndDate < s.EndDate
UNION ALL
SELECT
  c.PRODUCTKEY, c.STYLE, c.SIZE
  , s.BeginDate
  , DATEADD(day,-1,c.BeginDate)
  , s.Price
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN prices s
 ON c.Style = s.Style
 AND s.Size IS NULL
 AND c.BeginDate > s.BeginDate AND c.BeginDate < s.EndDate
ORDER BY ProductKey,BeginDate
```